# An efficient way to iteratively substitute map values into another map with spark

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark

Lets say I have some data structure, it could be `List[Map[String, List[String]]]` or potentially `Dataset[Map[String, List[String]]]`

and it contains maps like the following

```
[a, (b)]
[b, (a, c, d)]
[c, (b, d)]
[d, (b, c)]
[e, (f, g)]
[f, (e)]
[g, (e, h)]
```

I would like to find a way to obtain the following

```
[a, (a, b, c, d)]
[b, (a, b, c, d)]
[c, (a, b, c, d)]
[d, (a, b, c, d)]
[e, (e, f, g, h)]
[f, (e, f, g, h)]
[g, (e, f, g, h)]
```

Is there a good way to code this up using spark?
And what would be the best data types/structures to use for this process?

The only way I can think to solve this is to continuously loop over the maps and perform substitutions, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Do you need to extract all groups of values relative to each other from original map?

Comment: essentially yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to use [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) algorithm.
There is an [example of implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/transitive_closure.py) with iterative join.

Comment: thank you, I implemented a solution using spark/emr and it worked incredibly well